# Kendo UI Multiselect Clear Button not working with Touch screen

Tags: kendo-ui

Im trying to use the Kendo MultiSelect component on mobile but having some issues. It looks like I can't use the clear button(s) on the kendo multi select component when I use touch events. The selected item will only clear if I touch slightly below the "x". The clear buttons work fine when I use the mouse.

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="example" role="application">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <h2>Invite Attendees</h2>
        <label for="required">Required</label>
        <select id="required" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">
            <option>Steven White</option>
            <option>Nige Buchanan</option>
            <option>Laura Fuller</option>
        </select>
        <label for="optional">Optional</label>
        <select id="optional" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">
            <option>Steven White</option>
        </select>
        <button class="k-button" id="get">Send Invitation</button>
    </div>
    <style>
        .demo-section label {
            display: block;
            margin: 15px 0 5px 0;
        }
        #get {
            float: right;
            margin: 25px auto 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // create MultiSelect from select HTML element
            var required = $("#required").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
            var optional = $("#optional").kendoMultiSelect({
                autoClose: false
            }).data("kendoMultiSelect");

            $("#get").click(function() {
                alert("Attendees:\n\nRequired: " + required.value() + "\nOptional: " + optional.value());
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please use code snippet format, it's hard to read as is

Comment: not really sure what you mean? just using the example from the kendo ui multiselect component
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index